# Create multiple variables of same size in Matlab

Tags: matlab, performance

Say, I want to create 3 variables of same size in MATLAB:

```
a = zeros(3,3);
b = zeros(3,3);
c = zeros(3,3);
```

Is there any fast way to do this, I know this is not working but I think of something like

```
a,b,c = zeros(3,3);
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use `deal` there is no need to wrap it in a cell as NKN suggested:

```
[a,b,c]=deal(zeros(3,3))
```

Comment: Thanks, deal does exactly what i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Although you can do this:

```
a = zeros(3); % a 3x3 zero matrix
b = a;
c = a;
```

If you define the values that you want to assign, in a cell, the other way (**faster**) is:

```
c={zeros(3)};
[a1,a2,a3,a4]=deal(c{1})
```

it means that you put your assigning value in a **cell** and then use **deal** function. Notice that the **a1,a2,a3,a4** does not have cell formats, but double formats and actually this is a very fast method.

If you use cell foramt you can assign more values at the same time, for example:

```
C = {rand(3) ones(3,1) eye(3) zeros(3,1)};
[a,b,c,d] = deal(C{:})
```

otherwise you can just get rid of the cell and use:

```
c=zeros(3);
[a1,a2,a3,a4]=deal(c);
```

as Daniel Suggested.